# find the argument that gives the nearest value of the function to the target value

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have a code that returns me the value of the *Price*.
Lets call it the black_box (so we don't know the function's form and its derivatives). It depends on a lot of arguments.
I want to find the value of the one argument (let's call it X) that gives me the nearest *Price* value to the Price_target value with the given tolerance.
For example:

```
Price_target = 100
tolerance = 1e-5
```

black_box(X) returns Price value and the optimization algorithm should give the X value that gives me the nearest to 100 value (Price_target).

Bounds also can be used here.

Looks like a one-dimensional problem, but it does not seem like a "minimization" problem.
What optimization algorithm I should use here? Can I use scipy here?

I tried something like that:

```
def func(X):
    Price_target = 100
    return black_box(X)-Price_target

res = scipy.optimize.minimize(f=func, x0=X, bounds=(50,150))
print(res.x)
```

But it does not help me.

Comment: minimize the squared difference?

Comment: How exactly would this not be a minimization problem? You're minimizing the difference between the black box and price target.

Comment: Which do you want, the *nearest value*, or a value *within the given tolerance*?

Comment: depends how black box behaves. if it's a convex function there will be a single minima which is the optimal solution, a simple gradient descent will do in that case. But if blackbox is a complex function with a ton of local minimas then you will need another approach. Usually you start a lot of seeds in random positions, let them converge to a minima, then take the best minima amongst them. Notice that this does not guarantee that you found the optimal one. even using bounds your function can have a fractal behavior, where optimal minima is unreachable if your resolution is too coarse